# dynamic_cast back to same object type fails with multiple inheritance and intermediate variable

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-cast, reinterpret-cast

Suppose a hierarchy with two unrelated polymorphic classes `PCH` and `GME`, a subclass `PCH_GME : public GME, public PCH`, and an object `gme_pch` of type `PCH_GME*`.

Why does the following sequence of casts of `gme_pch` "break" the cast back to the object's original type `GME_PCH*`:

```
GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();    
GME *gme = gme_pch;
PCH *pch = (PCH*)gme;
GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);
// same_as_gme_pch is NULL
```

whereas the following code does not break the casts:

```
GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();    
PCH *pch = gme_pch;    
GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);
// address of same_as_gme_pch == gme_pch
```

**Question:** Isn't each pointer always pointing to the same object, and shouldn't then the result of the final cast back to the original type always be the same?

EDIT: according to the answers, I added the output of the addresses of `gme_pch` and `pch`. And it shows that the relation of these two pointers in the variants that work is different from those where it does not work (i.e. depending on whether one writes `GME_PCE : public GME, public PCH` or `GME_PCE : public PCH, public GME`, `gme_pch` equals `pch` in the working variant and `gme_pch` is unequal in the non working variants and vice versa).

---

Just for making it easier to try things out, see the following code demonstrating variants of the above mentioned cast sequences; some working, some not:

```
class PCH {  // PrecachingHint
public:
    virtual std::string getHint() const = 0;
};

class GME {  // GenericModelElement
public:
    virtual std::string getKey() const = 0;
};

class GME_PCH : public GME, public PCH {
public:
    virtual std::string getHint() const { return "some hint"; }
    virtual std::string getKey() const { return "some key"; }
};

void castThatWorks() {

    GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

    PCH *pch = gme_pch;

    GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);

    std::cout << ((same_as_gme_pch == nullptr) ? "cast did not work." : "cast worked.")<< "gmepch:" << gme_pch << "; pch:" << pch << std::endl;
}

void castThatWorks2() {

    GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

    GME *gme = gme_pch;
    PCH *pch = dynamic_cast<PCH*>(gme);

    GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);

    std::cout << ((same_as_gme_pch == nullptr) ? "cast did not work." : "cast worked.")<< "gmepch:" << gme_pch << "; pch:" << pch << std::endl;
}

void castThatDoesntWork() {

    GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

    GME *gme = gme_pch;  // note: void* gme = gme_pch breaks the subsequent dynamic cast, too.
    PCH *pch = (PCH*)gme;

    GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);

    std::cout << ((same_as_gme_pch == nullptr) ? "cast did not work." : "cast worked.")<< "gmepch:" << gme_pch << "; pch:" << pch << std::endl;
}

void castThatDoesntWork2() {

    GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

    GME *gme = gme_pch;
    PCH *pch =  reinterpret_cast<PCH*>(gme);

    GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);

    std::cout << ((same_as_gme_pch == nullptr) ? "cast did not work." : "cast worked.")<< "gmepch:" << gme_pch << "; pch:" << pch << std::endl;
}

void castThatDoesntWork3() {

    GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

    GME *gme = gme_pch;
    PCH *pch = static_cast<PCH*>(static_cast<void*>(gme));

    GME_PCH *same_as_gme_pch = dynamic_cast<GME_PCH*>(pch);

    std::cout << ((same_as_gme_pch == nullptr) ? "cast did not work." : "cast worked.")<< "gmepch:" << gme_pch << "; pch:" << pch << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    castThatWorks();
    castThatWorks2();
    castThatDoesntWork();
    castThatDoesntWork2();
    castThatDoesntWork3();   
}
```

Output:

```
cast worked.gmepch:0x100600030; pch:0x100600038
cast worked.gmepch:0x100600040; pch:0x100600048
cast did not work.gmepch:0x100600260; pch:0x100600260
cast did not work.gmepch:0x100202c30; pch:0x100202c30
cast did not work.gmepch:0x100600270; pch:0x100600270
```

Comment: Note that the "don't work" versions use `reinterpret_cast` or equivalent, whereas the "work" versions only use implicit conversion and `dynamic_cast`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

GME *gme = gme_pch;
PCH *pch = static_cast<PCH*>(static_cast<void*>(gme));
```

is wrong when `GME_PCH` is multiply inherited from both `GME` and `PCH`. Don't use it.

You will notice why it is wrong by trying the following:

```
GME_PCH *gme_pch = new GME_PCH();

GME *gme = gme_pch;
PCH *pch1 = gme_pch;  // Implicit conversion. Does the right offsetting of pointer
PCH *pch2 = static_cast<PCH*>(static_cast<void*>(gme)); // Wrong.

std::cout << "pch1: " << pch1 << ", pch2: " << pch2 << std::endl;
```

You will notice that `pch1` and `pch2` are different. `pch1` is a valid value while `pch2` is not.

Comment: You'r right. I added output that shows that the pointer values in the working variant behaves differently from that in the non working ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you convert `GME_PCH *` to `PCH *` using implicit conversion, `static_cast`, or `dynamic_cast`,  then the result points to the `PCH` sub-object of the `GME_PCH` object.

However when you convert `GME_PCH *` to `PCH *` using `reinterpret_cast`, the result leaves the address unchanged: it points to the memory location of the `GME_PCH` object still, which usually is where the `GME` sub-object is located (compilers typically lay out polymorphic objects with the first base class first in memory).

[image]

Your non-working attempts are all equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<PCH *>(gme_pch)`. They fail because you end up with a pointer of type `PCH *` which is not pointing at a `PCH` object.

---

The C-style cast behaves like `static_cast` if that would be valid, otherwise it behaves like a `reinterpret_cast`.

The code `(PCH *)gme_pch` is `static_cast<PCH *>(gme_pch)`, but the code `(PCH *)gme` is `reinterpret_cast<PCH *>(gme)`.

To get to the `PCH` from a `GME` you need to use `dynamic_cast`, which is capable of testing whether the `GME` is actually part of a `GME_PCH` or not. If it isn't, the cast will yield null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`PCH *pch = (PCH*)gme;`

Stop using C style casts.  This line of code does nothing reasonable; it reinterprets the bits of `gme` as  a pointer to one thing and says "what if those bits referred to another type".

But the address of the GME and PCH subobjects are *not* the same, so the pointer you get is garbage.  Then everything else fails.

The line can also be written as `PCH *pch = reinterpret_cast<PCH*>(gme);`  C style casts can silently be reasonable or dangerous.

This `PCH *pch = static_cast<PCH*>(static_cast<void*>(gme));` violates a different rule; when casting to `void*` you should always cast back *to the exact same type* as you cast from.

There are cases where reinterpret cast (or wrong-tripping via void) works; but they are fragile and involve relatively esoteric text in the standard.

Simply always return a void ptr to its exact original type, and never reinterpret cast or C style cast pointers to other types.

Answer (score 1):

When inheritance is being used the pointer value needs to be adjusted from pointer to derived class to a potentially different pointer to base class even without multiple inheritance. For example if you add a virtual method in derived class pointer to base class will be typically adjusted by size of pointer to vtable:

```
struct foo
{
    int whatever;
};

struct bar: public foo
{
    virtual void what();
};
```

> bar layout:
>
> > pvtable ← bar * will point here
> >
> > int     ← foo * will point here

Moreover, in case of virtual inheritance it won't be possible to figure out correct pointer adjustment so the actual value of base class pointer is explicitly stored in each derived class instance.

Comment: "_so the actual value of base class pointer is explicitly stored in each derived class instance._" Not always. It can be found via the vptr